# Python: obtain max from json file

Tags: python, json

I have this json file

```
myjson=[{u'faceRectangle': {u'height': 72, u'left': 214, u'top': 125, u'width': 72}, u'scores': {u'anger': 0.180509463,
 u'contempt': 1.50903434e-05, u'disgust': 0.008213697, u'fear': 0.418243885, u'happiness': 0.0259612668, u'neutral': 0.0001996803, u'sadness': 0.00102899456, u'surprise': 0.365827948}}]
```

I want to print from `scores` the sentiment that has the biggest probability with its probability next to it.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function with a `key` that selects the probability value for each item in the dictionary:

```
>>> myjson = [{'faceRectangle': {'left': 214, 'width': 72, 'top': 125, 'height': 72}, 'scores': {'surprise': 0.365827948, 'disgust': 0.008213697, 'sadness': 0.00102899456, 'contempt': 1.50903434e-05, 'happiness': 0.0259612668, 'anger': 0.180509463, 'neutral': 0.0001996803, 'fear': 0.418243885}}]
>>> max(myjson[0]['scores'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
('fear', 0.418243885)
```

`myjson[0]` selects the *first* dictionary from the list and `max()` is then applied to the nested `scores` dictionary.

You can also use `operator.itemgetter()` as the key function:

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(myjson[0]['scores'].items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Mmm. Interesting downvote. Care to explain?

Comment: thanks. is a good answer for me!